# php replace newline and character not unwrapping text

Tags: php

The replace function is removing all the equal signs but it is not unwrapping the text.

$text

```
I will be doing a Training next Thursday morning @ 1am in Gal=
laway. Please let me know if you plan on attending and I =
will send out another reminder next week prior to that time. This is predo=
minately for new users (or those who would like a refresher course). I wil=
l touch base briefly on registrations and would be happy to stay after to r=
eview any more advanced booking issues or questions you might have.

Facilities Coordinator
```

php

```
$text = str_replace("=\n", "", $text);
```

Comment: Text seems unwrapped here:  http://3v4l.org/XUMD8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with PHP_EOL is to find the newline character:

```
str_replace( "=" . PHP_EOL, "", $text )
```

PHP_EOL constant is holding the line break characters used on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Normalize your line endings first

```
$text = preg_replace("/\r\n?/s", '\n', $text );
```

for a single line you could try this, note the "s" -   and "m"  modifiers - that seemed to work in a regx tester I tried it on but not 100% sure it would work.

```
$text = preg_replace("/=$\r?\n?/ms", "", $text);
```

PHP_EOL will work if its content created on the server, however if its a file created on a different file system it won't help, if memory serves me right.

Comment: Can be written as `'/=\R/'`, since `\R` by default matches any unicode newlines sequences.